# How can I include HTML sections in XSL template?

Tags: html, xslt, cdata

I have an XSL template that is a small section of an HTML email.  The XSL section changes based on data, but the surrounding HTML does not.  I would like to include this HTML in the XSL template.  I tried the following approach, but get an exception because the tags in the EmailHeader.html are not closed.  I tried using CDATA tags, but with no success.

***My exception:  Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: td, tr, table, td, tr, table, body, html.***

How can I include the html sections in the XSL template?

(Code samples have been simplified)

**My XSL File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

     <xsl:template match="/Email">    

     <xsl:copy-of select="document('EmailHeader.html')"></xsl:copy-of>

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="width:25px">&#160;</td>
        <td style="width:550px; text-align:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; color:#444444">
          <br /><br />
          To <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>:
          <br /><br />
          Welcome, and thank you for enrolling...
         </td>
        <td style="width:25px">&#160;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <xsl:copy-of select="document('EmailFooter.html')"></xsl:copy-of>

   </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**EmailHeader.html:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color:#96A084">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#96A084; margin:0px; padding:0px">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="630px" style="background-color:#96A084">
  <tr>
    <td>
```

**EmailFooter.html:**

```
    <td style="width:15px">&#160;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why can't you just actually literally insert these html elements in the document?

Comment: I can, but I want to keep them separate so that if/when they change, I don't have to edit every XSL file that I have (could be hundreds).  The Header & Footer maintain the look/structure of the email and the XSL is just the dynamic text that populates it.  Make sense?

Comment: how about reversing it? In other words, have your header/footer in one XSL file, and import the content. That should keep everything well formed...

Comment: I'm trying that.  Currently getting an error The 'img' start tag on line 96 position 36 does not match the end tag of 'a' on a simple piece of code <a href="www.url.com"><img src="image.jpg"></img></a>

Comment: Also, if I reverse it and call the XSL with the header/footer which includes the a link to the dynamic XSL, the included XSL fields are not populated.  In other words, the mapping of the XML fields does not seem to reach the file included by the <xsl:copy-if> node.  ANy thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do, is create your complete Email template in a separate file, and then pass the body of the email to it as a parameter. For example, save the following XSLT in a file called **EmailTemplate.xslt**

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:template name="Email">
      <xsl:param name="body"/>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="background-color:#96A084">
         <head>
            <title/>
         </head>
         <body style="background-color:#96A084; margin:0px; padding:0px">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="630px" style="background-color:#96A084">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <xsl:copy-of select="$body"/>
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:15px"> </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Next, amend your original XSLT to import this file, and then call the named **Email** template with the HTML for the email body as a parameter

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:include href="EmailTemplate.xslt"/>

   <xsl:output method="html"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Email">
      <xsl:variable name="body">
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
               <td style="width:25px"> </td>
               <td style="width:550px; text-align:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; color:#444444">
                  <br/>
                  <br/> To 
                  <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>: 
                  <br/>
                  <br/>Welcome, and thank you for enrolling... 
               </td>
               <td style="width:25px"> </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:call-template name="Email">
         <xsl:with-param name="body" select="$body"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

So, when you apply this XSLT to the following XML

```
<Email>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
</Email>
```

The following should be output

```
<html style="background-color:#96A084" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#96A084; margin:0px; padding:0px">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="630px" style="background-color:#96A084">
<tr>
<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" xmlns=""><tr><td style="width:25px"> </td><td style="width:550px; text-align:left; font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt; color:#444444"><br><br> To 
                  John 
                  Smith: 
                  <br><br>Welcome, and thank you for enrolling... 
               </td><td style="width:25px"> </td></tr></table>
</td>
<td style="width:15px"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```